# PHP fopen path is not working

Tags: php, path, fopen

I am trying to write to a random file with PHP. 
PHP script is located in /var/www/html/
the random files that I am trying create resides in /var/www/html/print folder.

I am using following javascript

```
<button id="button1" type="button">Write to File</button>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#button1').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "printed.php",
            data: "",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Some error occured");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and following php to write the files.

```
<?php
$filename = rand(5, 15);
$path = "/print/"
@ $fp = fopen("$path""$filename", "wb");
if (!$fp) {
    echo '<p><strong>Cannot generate message file</strong></p></body></html>';
    exit;
} else {
    $outputstring  = 'Hello, i have been generated by the button';
    fwrite($fp, $outputstring);
    Echo "Message inserted";
}
?>
```

If I don't use the path in PHP file is created successfully but in /var/www/html folder, I want the files to be created in /var/www/html/print folder.

But if I use the file path, I get following error in the logs.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '@' in
>   /netboot/var/www/html/printed.php on line 4

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on line 3, and a comma on line 4. It's either laziness or fatigue.

Comment: You're missing the file extension of the file you are trying to write to as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot to add semicolon (;).

Change

```
$path = "/print/"
@ $fp = fopen("$path""$filename", "wb");
```

To this

```
$path = "/print/";
@ $fp = fopen("$path" . "$filename", "wb");
```

Comment: Yes you are right, this now works.

Comment: You may want to change your answer to mention adding the `.`

Answer (score 1):

You have error in syntax.

```
@ $fp = fopen("$path""$filename", "wb");
```

Correct statement.

```
@ $fp = fopen("$path"."$filename", "wb");
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No, this does not work, I get the same error message.

Comment: This actually works, I missed the semicolon end of the $path variable.